# multithreading process in C++, all threads are ended up without completion

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I run the following code using pthread.h...
While run, before the thread finishes, the code exits...

I attached the code...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    long tid = (long)threadid;
    cout<<"Hello World! Thread ID,"<<tid<<endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return &tid;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
    {
        cout<<"main() : creating thread,"<<i<<endl;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)i);
        //sleep(1);
        if(rc)
        {
            cout<<"Error:Unable to create thread,"<<rc<<endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `join` all threads before call to `pthread_exit` in main.

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
   pthread_join(threads[i], 0);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks.. Its working..Please say what is sleep() function and which header it is?.

Comment: @Vinoj [Sleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your main you do,

```
   pthread_exit(NULL); // this causes main to do its own work and exit. 
                       // and the other thread will keep running at its own pace
```

As stated [here](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixthreads.html#preface)

you must use something like

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
   pthread_join(&threads[i],NULL);
}
```

in main to make it wait for all threads to end before proceeding